# How to center column name of table on certain columns in latex?

Tags: latex

I am very new to latex. I cannot figure out how to have "Results" centered on columns 2-5 rather than the whole table. Below is the code I tried and and "Results" is centered on columns 1 to 5.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuRsp.png

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{49pt}}lrrrr@{}}  \toprule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Results} \\ \cline{2-5}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make a small, but compileable test document ([mre]) instead of this code fragement?

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, I edited my post! Would this be considered a small reproducible example? Any feedback on the posting format is welcome as I am very new to posting here and using latex.

Comment: Thanks for editing! However the problem was not the length of code, but rather the missing document structure around it. In its current form trying to help you would require to first setting up a new document, then guess the packages necessary to compile your code fragment etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` is missing in front of `\multicolumn` to separate it from the first column.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{49pt}}lrrrr@{}}  \toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Results} \\ \cline{2-5}
Variables & $\beta$ & $\emph{sr}$ & $\emph{t}$ & $\emph{p}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
  
\end{document}
```

[image]